# how can I make an app the displays all permanent google+ hangouts and the people in them?

Tags: google-plus

I'm completely new to using the Google+ apis and the quickstart guides are a bit confusing (i tried the ruby version since i'm probably most familiar there. looks like this: https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-ruby)

and I've also looked at the google hangout apis - but those seem to be more for augmenting hangouts (i.e. once you're in a hangout, you'd see the extension, etc. you built).

what I'd like to do is create a place for everyone at my company to log in and see a list of all the permanent hangouts I've created and see who's currently joined that hangout (and which hangouts are available for a meeting).

I'm really sorry for the question but any help getting started is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no API that is officially provided that can tell you what hangouts are currently available. If you are interested in seeing one, you may wish to see if the feature has been requested at https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list and, if not, request it.

Your question, however, seems to have an assumption that I'm not entirely sure is valid. What do you mean by a "permanent hangout"? In general, hangouts are created and destroyed on an ad-hoc basis (although there are some exceptions).

One of those exceptions are for hangouts that are tied to calendar events (as you note). In these cases, you can use the Calendar API to get the Event resource and get the hangout URL from that (see https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events and related pages for the API), but it still won't report who is in a hangout at any given time.

One way you can approach what you're doing is to have your website have virtual meeting topics and when someone joins one of these topics, they run an app that reports back to your website the URL of the hangout they're in. Your website can then include this "room information" as associated with the topic on the website for others to see. This solution is outlined in the video at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Al4SbeVyLm4.

Comment: if you go to google+ events, create an even, make it online only using the advanced settings, the link for the hangout created for that event will persist until the end of the meeting. If you schedule the meeting far enough out, it is effectively permanent.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a reference to the calendar API, since G+ events are reflected as Calendar Events as well. Unfortunately, it still doesn't address the need to see who is in the hangout, and using the hangout app solution is the best approach to this at the moment.

Comment: so I'm confused here (obviously) what does this call do: gapi.hangout.getParticipants()

Comment: Just what it says, but it needs to be run from someone inside the hangout, as you observed in your initial question.

Comment: ah! I see. basically useless in this case. Thanks for the info!